Unable to use CkHttpW to download a file on one users computer
<ChilkatLog>
  <Download>
    <DllDate>Mar 29 2024</DllDate>
    <ChilkatVersion>9.5.0.98</ChilkatVersion>
    <UnlockPrefix>AJTRCK</UnlockPrefix>
    <UnlockStatus>2</UnlockStatus>
    <Architecture>Little Endian; 32-bit</Architecture>
    <Language>Visual C++ 2022 (32-bit)</Language>
    <VerboseLogging>0</VerboseLogging>
    <url>xxx</url>
    <toLocalPath>yyy</toLocalPath>
    <currentWorkingDir>C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant</currentWorkingDir>
    <a_httpDownload>
      <httpDownloadFile>
        <localFilePath>yyy</localFilePath>
        <localFileAlreadyExists>1</localFileAlreadyExists>
        <quickHttpRequest>
          <httpVerb>GET</httpVerb>
          <url>xxx</url>
          <openHttpConnection>
            <info>Opening connection directly to HTTP server.</info>
            <httpHostname>www.publictalksoftware.co.uk</httpHostname>
            <httpPort>443</httpPort>
            <tls>True</tls>
            <socket2Connect>
              <connect2>
                <connectImplicitSsl>
                  <connectSocket_v2>
                    <connect_domain>
                      <ckDnsResolveDomainIPv4_n>
                        <domainName>www.publictalksoftware.co.uk</domainName>
                        <doDnsQuery>
                          <dns_over_udp>
                            <error>Waited, but no data ready on UDP socket.</error>
                            <idleTimeoutMs>30000</idleTimeoutMs>
                          </dns_over_udp>
                          <error>DNS query failed.</error>
                        </doDnsQuery>
                        <num_app_defined_ns>3</num_app_defined_ns>
                        <error>Failed to do DNS query....</error>
                        <domain>www.publictalksoftware.co.uk</domain>
                        <namservers>
                          <ip>181.213.132.2</ip>
                          <ip>181.213.132.3</ip>
                          <ip>192.168.0.254</ip>
                        </namservers>
                      </ckDnsResolveDomainIPv4_n>
                    </connect_domain>
                  </connectSocket_v2>
                </connectImplicitSsl>
                <connectFailReason>0</connectFailReason>
                <ConnectFailReason>0</ConnectFailReason>
              </connect2>
            </socket2Connect>
            <connect>Socket operation timeout.</connect>
          </openHttpConnection>
        </quickHttpRequest>
        <outputLocalFileSize>0</outputLocalFileSize>
        <numOutputBytesWritten>0</numOutputBytesWritten>
        <error>httpDownloadFile failed.</error>
      </httpDownloadFile>
      <error>a_httpDownload failed.</error>
    </a_httpDownload>
    <totalElapsedMs>31000</totalElapsedMs>
    <errorResponseBodySize>0</errorResponseBodySize>
    <error>Failed.</error>
  </Download>
</ChilkatLog>

I am downloading the file using the Chilkat library. One specific user encounters this error. They say they have switched off antivirus and firewall and it still happens.
They can manually download the file from the internet using their browser though.
My code is simple:
CkHttpW http;
if (http.Download(strDownloadURL, strTargetZIP))
{
    // Snip
}
else
{
    CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::ShowChilkatErrorLog(
        CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd), http.lastErrorXml());
}

Update
I updated Chilkat to the latest version and asked the user to try again. This time I asked them to try a different feature which checks for updates. Same issue:
<ChilkatLog>
  <Download>
    <DllDate>Jun 28 2024</DllDate>
    <ChilkatVersion>9.5.0.99</ChilkatVersion>
    <UnlockPrefix>AJTRCK</UnlockPrefix>
    <UnlockStatus>2</UnlockStatus>
    <Architecture>Little Endian; 64-bit</Architecture>
    <Language>Visual C++ 2022 / x64</Language>
    <VerboseLogging>0</VerboseLogging>
    <url>xxx</url>
    <toLocalPath>C:\Users\crism\AppData\Roaming\Meeting Schedule Assistant\AutoUpdate\MWBDataUpdate.zip</toLocalPath>
    <currentWorkingDir>C:\Program Files\Meeting Schedule Assistant</currentWorkingDir>
    <a_httpDownload>
      <httpDownloadFile>
        <localFilePath>yyy</localFilePath>
        <localFileAlreadyExists>1</localFileAlreadyExists>
        <quickHttpRequest>
          <httpVerb>GET</httpVerb>
          <url>https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/mwbdata/MWBDataUpdate.zip</url>
          <openHttpConnection>
            <info>Opening connection directly to HTTP server.</info>
            <httpHostname>www.publictalksoftware.co.uk</httpHostname>
            <httpPort>443</httpPort>
            <tls>True</tls>
            <socket2Connect>
              <connect2>
                <connectImplicitSsl>
                  <connectSocket_v2>
                    <connect_domain>
                      <ckDnsResolveDomainIPv4_n>
                        <domainName>www.publictalksoftware.co.uk</domainName>
                        <doDnsQuery>
                          <dns_over_udp>
                            <error>Waited, but no data ready on UDP socket.</error>
                            <idleTimeoutMs>30000</idleTimeoutMs>
                          </dns_over_udp>
                          <error>DNS query failed.</error>
                        </doDnsQuery>
                        <num_app_defined_ns>3</num_app_defined_ns>
                        <error>Failed to do DNS query....</error>
                        <domain>www.publictalksoftware.co.uk</domain>
                        <namservers>
                          <ip>181.213.132.2</ip>
                          <ip>181.213.132.3</ip>
                          <ip>192.168.0.254</ip>
                        </namservers>
                      </ckDnsResolveDomainIPv4_n>
                    </connect_domain>
                  </connectSocket_v2>
                </connectImplicitSsl>
                <connectFailReason>0</connectFailReason>
                <ConnectFailReason>0</ConnectFailReason>
              </connect2>
            </socket2Connect>
            <connect>Socket operation timeout.</connect>
          </openHttpConnection>
        </quickHttpRequest>
        <error>httpDownloadFile failed.</error>
      </httpDownloadFile>
      <error>a_httpDownload failed.</error>
    </a_httpDownload>
    <totalElapsedMs>30485</totalElapsedMs>
    <errorResponseBodySize>0</errorResponseBodySize>
    <error>Failed.</error>
  </Download>
</ChilkatLog>


A browser uses HTTP with a transport layer of TCP. XML error indicates the connection was using dns_over_udp.  Not sure if this is issue.  Just an observation.   I wondering if two connections are used.  A main connection and then a secondary connection to do download.   CKHTTPW is unicode while without the final w (CKHTTP) is UTF-8.  I would try CKHTTP.

Test using the latest version of Chilkat (v9.5.0.99)

@ChilkatSoftware I got him to try with latest version. Same issue as before. Updated question.

@ChilkatSoftware Problem solved. They uninstalled my program again, cleaned the registry, changed the Wifi connection and redid the installation. Everything went well.
